# AngularJS theme API modification - Locking Check Box Action Values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, header

I am new to coding. I am trying to build a website from a theme layout that I bought from Themeforest. I don't have problems editing the code, but there's one thing that I am not getting it right. I need to make the header fixed. I have the following code in the file:

```
<div class="m-b-sm">
<label class="i-switch bg-info pull-right">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="app.settings.asideFixed">
</label>
```

The above code will activate a button on the side of the page, that we can turn on to make the header fixed. But I would like the header to be fixed always.

Can someone help me? Thanks `;)`

Comment: The vote to close for "off topic", whomever did that, is in the wrong, "unclear what you're asking" is better.This question is perfectly on-topic, there just isn't enough information to really know what's going on. 

Francisco, you're saying that when the check box is checked, the header becomes fixed? I'm sure there is some `Javascript` that can auto-check it to run whatever API (themeforest) you've installed and switch to fixed, and then keep it checked. You might want to consider adding javascript to your question's tags if this is the case.

Good luck learning to program, it's great fun :D

Comment: You are using AngularJS here to bind the Checkbox status to CSS Property. You could resolve this issue in two different ways: 
ONE : Remove the CHECKBOX from the HTML, go into your app.js(Angular), set $scope.app.settings.asideFixed = true, or simply EDIT CSS to address both. Good Luck

Comment: Well, I would ask you to use the ThemeForest's theme support option and ask the question there instead, because the context will be known to the author and at the same time, you cannot share your code, that has been purchased from Themeforest!

Comment: @PraveenKumar I second that.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Are you using script to edit posts to make it seem like you've made changes? Why did you tag the emoticon? That's something a robot would do because it looks like code??? `:)` I'm messing with you of course, but it is pretty funny haha

Comment: LoL. I love having the emoticon to have a border or background to it! `:P` « Like this! No I am using my 10 fingers to edit the post! `:D`

Answer (score 1):

I'm ignoring the fact that you're using AngularJS, since you're saying the button is working.

I believe that piece of code is useless to help you.

### Using "Inspect Element"

Click the right button of the mouse on the header element and check if there's an "**Inspect element**" entry (or something similar) in the context menu. You'll find it with Chrome, Firefox and Opera. I believe the new versions of Internet Explorer have this feature out of the box.

The goal is to see how the "class" and "style" attributes of the header element are changed.

Make the header fixed (click the button), and you may see how the attributes of the header element are changed.

If the "class" or the "style" attribute is changed when you click the button, change the HTML file accordingly and remove the code for the button.

### Changing the CSS file

You can also change the CSS file to make it work if the header element has an "id" attribute.
In that case, find "property: fixed" in the CSS file. If it does not exist, find "property: absolute".

Make sure it's supposed to be applied to the header element (use the "Inspect element", or change the properties, save the file and see how the web page is changed).

You'd need to replace the selector (the expression before the opening curly bracket: **{**).

If the header element does not have the "id" attribute (in the HTML code), add it.

Replace the selector with the id attribute value prepended cardinal: **#**.

Remove the code for the button.

For instance:

(in the HTML file)

```
<header id="head">
<!-- some stuff here -->
</header>
```

(in the CSS file)

```
#head { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

You can also add the style directly to the element:

```
<header style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;">
<!-- some stuff here -->
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the theme uses BootStrap, you can use the fixed header by adding a class `navbar-fixed-top` to the navigation bar. The code might be similar to:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  ...
</div>
```